# Android - Where to implement onBufferingUpdate(...) using VideoView and MediaController

Tags: android, buffer, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am confused by the `MediaController` and `VideoView` APIs in Android.

I am using it to stream videos through HTTP, which is working fine. Only problem is that it stops for buffering from time to time. I now want to get notified whenever the video starts to buffer to display a progress indicator.

I learned that I need to implement `public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)` from `android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener`, my question is just *where do I have to implement it*? I followed the advice from another SO question and implemented:

```
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "onPrepared called");

            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                //do something
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG, "Buffering update: " +  percent + "%");

                }
            });
        }
```

But it didn't work... Do I have to subclass `VideoView` and implement it there??

Comment: Did you get solution to this problem ? I am facing the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Works:

```
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
         {
             @Override
             public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
              {

                    myVideoView.start();

                   if ( dialog != null )
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) 
                        {

                            Log.d("URL", "Buffering update: " +  percent + "%");

                        }
                    });


             }
        });        

        Dialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);

        myVideoView.setVideoURI( Uri.parse( "http://..." ) );
```